# Executing root commands from PHP...Is there a safe way?

Tags: php, command, root

I was thinking about to make a little web-based Linux control panel (just for fun).

First potential problem that came to my mind is that i would need to give Apache's user root-level permissions to run those commands, which would compromise the security of the whole system.

Installing a dedicated web server for the system is not really an option.

Maybe I could run a 2nd Apache instance (keeping the 1st one for regular users) but not even sure if possible.

So, what you guys think?
What are my best options here?

Thanks in advance for any input.

EDIT: Ok guys thanks for all the suggestions, i'll keep them in mind.

Comment: The security features you will need to consider, sidestep, or overcome are numerous. Don't even think about attempting this unless you have serious extensive knowledge of Linux systems security.

Comment: Anytime you're tempted to do something like **this**, why not ask the Plesk people how much fun it is to [make a "safe" web-based system admin panel](http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2012/02/plesk-control-panel-bug-left-ftc-sites-and-thousands-more-exposed-to-anon.ars).

Comment: I was thinking about to make a little web-based Linux control panel (just for fun) - I am thinking you should get out more, but then again I should do something about my insomnia!

Answer (score 5):

Write specific scripts that can be run as root and use the setuid bit to do it, so that Apache can run just those scripts as root. IE

```
#! /usr/bin/php (or wherever your php binary is)
<?php
   // Some PHP code that takes in very limited user input,
   // validates it carefully, and does a sequence of actions
   // that you need to run as root.

   // This could easily be a shell script (or whatever else you want)
   // instead of PHP. That might be preferable in many situations.
?>
```

Then make sure that that script is owned by root and group'd by your user that Apache runs as:

```
chown root:www-data myscript.php
```

Then make it run as owner:

```
chmod u+s myscript.php
```

And make sure that Apache can execute it:

```
chmod g+x myscript.php
```

Comment: Running PHP with setuid, this just reeks of potential security issues but yeah, that's what OP wants :)

Comment: Linux ignores setuid bit on interpreted languages as it is considered extremely insecure. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts/2910#2910

Answer (score 3):

Executing root commands via webserver seems like an insane idea to me, but anyway.

You could use [`sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) which would make sure that you won't run any unwanted commands.

Little example taken from [here](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_%3a_Ch09_%3a_Linux_Users_and_Sudo), sudo config:

```
peter, %operator ALL= /sbin/, /usr/sbin, /usr/local/apps/check.pl
```

And in php:

```
exec( 'sudo /usr/local/apps/check.pl ...');
```

Be sure to escape all arguments correctly and so on.

Or you could rather build db table like this:

```
commands (
    action,
    serialized_parameters.
    result,
    return_code
)
```

Use php to insert commands to this table and the another script which will be run in cron by different user. You won't have real time results (but you can have them 30 seconds old) but apache user won't be able to use any command directly (of course you can limit actions easily when reading records).

Answer (score 2):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell (as root if requested), it solves the limitations of exec() and shell_exec(). Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd('yourFirstCommand');
//the return will be a string containing the return of the command
echo $return1;
```

In terms of security it is far better than running apache as root. But letting PHP anywhere near root is always tricky.

The project i built achieves a root bash shell in one of 2 ways:

1) You allow apache the right to sudo python.

OR

2) You pass root credentials to the object every time you need a shell with root setup.

Pick your poison. :) Read the documentation.